# FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 character ' ' not supported here

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am getting this error:

> 'FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 character ' ' not supported here'

while executing the following query on Hive:

```
create external table hbaselabreport(key string,patientname string)
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
 with serdeproperties("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,pd:patientname",
"hbase.table.name"="labreport")
```

hbase and hive are installed on localhost and labreport table is on hbase.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `TBLPROPERTIES`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbaselabreport(key string,patientname string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,pd:patientname") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name"="labreport")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!! I identified the issue -having blank space just before 'with serdeproperties' now it is running